# change the navigationbar backgroundcolor for a tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

My UI is just from TabBarController A to TabBarController B, those two TabBarController with different child items. Now I want to change the TabBarController B's navigationbar backgroundColor, but any of those methods followed are not work.

*tabBarViewControllerA.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
babBarViewControllerB.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
babBarViewControllerB.childViewControllers.firstObject.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];*

Also, from the debug->view debugging->capture view hierarchy, I can see the navigationbar backgroundcolor has changed, but the finial color is not changes.
Please give me some ideas about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

found that just need to change the navigationbar.bartintcolor

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```